# Trying to print out response message from object

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

Here is my error callback function from an ajax call.

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON( xhr.responseText );
}
```

From that I am sending this to the console:

```
console.log(responseObj.message);
```

Which is returning this:

```
Object {Invalid or missing parameters: Object}
    Invalid or missing parameters: Object 
        email_already_in_use: "'Email' already in use"
```

If I stringify the response like this:

```
var responseMsg = responseObj.message;
if(typeof responseMsg =='object') {
    var respObj = JSON.stringify(responseMsg);
    console.log(respObj);
}
```

I get this:

```
{"Invalid or missing parameters":{"email_already_in_use":"'Email' already in use"}}
```

How can I print to the user that their email is already in use?

complete callback function:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {

    var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON( xhr.responseText );
    var responseMsg = responseObj.message;

    if(typeof responseMsg =='object') {

        var respObj = JSON.stringify(responseMsg);
        console.log(respObj);

    } else {

        if(responseMsg ===false) {

            console.log('response false');

        } else {

            console.log('response something else');

        }
    }
      console.log(responseObj.message);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var errorMessages = responseObj.message["Invalid or missing parameters"];

for (var key in errorMessages) {
  if(errorMessages.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log(errorMessages[key]);
  }
}
```

If you have different kinds of messages (not only "Invalid or missing parameters"), you should iterate the message array first:

```
var errorMessages = responseObj.message;
for (var errorType in errorMessages){
  if(errorMessages.hasOwnProperty(errorType)){
    console.log(errorType + ":");
    var specificErrorMsgs = errorMessages[errorType];
    for (var message in specificErrorMsgs) {
      if(specificErrorMsgs.hasOwnProperty(message)){
        console.log(specificErrorMsgs[message]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```